# Trying to get session ID from cookie in Codeigniter but...

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve the session id from $_REQUEST/$_COOKIE in Codeigniter.  The problem is it returns the following and I don't know how to access it:

```
a:4:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"f42269d0f23d0310b0274a580c90627e";s:10:"ip_address";s:13:"128.128.128.128";s:10:"user_agent";s:50:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/2010010";s:13:"last_activity";i:1311979074;}ffcb685c182ffbbb1affd1ee49a558df
```

What in the world is that and how to I pull the session id(f42269d0f23d0310b0274a580c90627e)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's php serialize() output, use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php to convert it back to PHP data type

Comment: Argh!  Sometimes I wish my brain would retain more information.  Thank you for answering this quickly!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're accessing session data incorrectly. The serialized data you are seeing is stored in the database or if you're not using database, in the session cookie. To get the session ID you should be using the Codeigniter session "userdata".

So to get the session ID you would go: `$this->session->userdata('session_id');`

Remember that Codeigniter sessions aren't native PHP sessions, so you sort of have to use the session class function to get the values correctly. My understanding of the *unserialize()* function is that it is pretty expensive in performance and you probably don't want that added overhead of using it unnecessarily.

Comment: You are correct, but I am trying to read the cookie session id.  I figured it would be an easy way to verify an ajax request?

Comment: Codeigniter has in-built functionality to detect if a request is an AJAX request. It detects the headers being sent with the AJAX request, if you're using jQuery to perform your AJAX requests, I think it sends the appropriate headers. This function might be what you're after: $this->input->is_ajax_request() - check out the documentation for the input class here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html